# Remove padding-top on v-main in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How to remove the padding-top on v-main while on desktop view?

I tried `<v-main class="pt-0">` but it also remove in mobile view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this i hope it will work;

"pt-xl-0" for large screen,

"pt-md-0" for medium screen,

"pt-sm-0"  or "pt-xs-0" for mobile screen,

"pt-0" for every screen

```
<v-main class="pt-2 pt-sm-2 pt-xs-2 pt-md-0 pt-lg-0 pt-xl-0">
```

for more refrence https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/spacing/

Comment: shorter: `<v-main class="pt-2 pt-md-0">`